# Users access to subsite but no acces to root site

Tags: 2013, user, access, sub-site

In SP2013, I have AD users. I have :

- site1
- - subsite1
- - - sub_subsite1
- - - sub_subsite2

I want the users to access to sub_subsite1, for example, but no access to subsite1 or site1.
I know this is possible, but I'm getting confused by googling that.

I'm sure this is pretty simple for you :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the sub sites by default inherit permission from the parent site.

you can go to --> Site Setting --> Site permissions of your sub site i.e sub_subsite1

and click on stop inheriting Permission and add your user to that site.also remove the user from the parent site.the user can access only the sub site.

Comment: If that all ? I mean, break inheritance on root site, delete users from root site, then add them to sub_subsite1 ? Should I break the inheritance in subsite1 and delete users too ? If I just want them to see sub_subsite1 and not subsite1 ?

Comment: you don't need to break inheritance in subsite1 you need to remove the user from the subsite1.